# How to load a PBR texture map into blender and apply it to a mesh?

Tags: python, materials

I am trying to add new materials to a mesh and for this purpose, I need to load PBR materials from maps using blender API. I am using the class `MDLMaterial` in the following code snipet to load mdl materials:

```
import uuid
import bpy
import json

from pathlib import Path

import math

import warnings

import mdl
from brender.mesh import PASS_INDEX_UV_DENSITY_MULT
from toolbox.io.images import load_image, load_hdr


class BlenderMaterial(object):
    _next_id = 0

    def __init__(self, bobj=None, name=None, **kwargs):
        if name and not bobj:
            self.name = name
        elif bobj:
            self.name = bobj.name
        else:
            self.name = f'brender_material_{BlenderMaterial._next_id}_{uuid.uuid4()}'

        if bobj is None:
            self._bobj_was_given = False
            if self.name in bpy.data.materials:
                raise ValueError(f'Blender material {self.name!r} already '
                                 f'exists')
            BlenderMaterial._next_id += 1
            bpy.data.materials.new(name=self.name)
            self._bobj = bpy.data.materials[self.name]
            print(f'Created new material {self.name}')
        else:
            self._bobj_was_given = True
            self._bobj = bobj

    @property
    def bobj(self):
        return self._bobj

    def mean_roughness(self) -> float:
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __del__(self):
        pass


class NodesMaterial(BlenderMaterial):
    def __init__(self,
                 uv_ref_scale=1.0,
                 uv_translation=(0, 0),
                 uv_rotation=0,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bobj.use_nodes = True
        self.uv_ref_scale = uv_ref_scale
        self.uv_translation = uv_translation
        self.uv_rotation = uv_rotation

        # self.clear_nodes()
        self.uv_ref_scale_node = None

        nodes = self.bobj.node_tree.nodes
        if 'Material Output' not in nodes:
            output_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeOutput")
            output_node.name = "Material Output"

        self.init_nodes()

    def clear_nodes(self):
        self.bobj.node_tree.nodes.clear()
        self.bobj.node_tree.links.clear()
        nodes = self.bobj.node_tree.nodes
        output_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeOutput")
        output_node.name = "Material Output"

    @property
    def has_uvs(self):
        return self.uv_ref_scale_node is not None

    def connect_scale_node(self, map_nodes):
        nodes = self.bobj.node_tree.nodes
        links = self.bobj.node_tree.links

        uv_node = self.init_uv_node(nodes, links)

        for map_node in map_nodes:
            links.new(map_node.inputs[0], uv_node.outputs[0])

    def set_uv_ref_scale(self, uv_ref_scale):
        self.uv_ref_scale = uv_ref_scale
        self.update_uv_node()

    def update_uv_node(self):
        if self.uv_ref_scale_node is None:
            raise ValueError('UV scale node has not been initialized yet.')

        self.uv_ref_scale_node.outputs[0].default_value = self.uv_ref_scale

    def init_uv_node(self, nodes, links):
        self.uv_ref_scale_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeValue')
        self.update_uv_node()

        obj_info_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeObjectInfo')
        obj_info_to_uv_density_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMath')
        obj_info_to_uv_density_node.operation = 'DIVIDE'
        obj_info_to_uv_density_node.inputs[1].default_value = \
            PASS_INDEX_UV_DENSITY_MULT
        links.new(obj_info_to_uv_density_node.inputs[0], obj_info_node.outputs[1])

        # Divide our desired scale by the object UV density:
        #   uv_scale = uv_ref_scale / uv_density
        uv_scale_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMath')
        uv_scale_node.operation = 'DIVIDE'
        links.new(uv_scale_node.inputs[0], self.uv_ref_scale_node.outputs[0])
        links.new(uv_scale_node.inputs[1],
                  obj_info_to_uv_density_node.outputs[0])

        uv_map_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeUVMap")
        separate_uv_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeSeparateXYZ")
        combine_uv_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeCombineXYZ")

        links.new(separate_uv_node.inputs[0], uv_map_node.outputs[0])

        for i in [0, 1, 2]:
            mult_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeMath")
            mult_node.operation = 'MULTIPLY'
            links.new(mult_node.inputs[0], separate_uv_node.outputs[i])
            links.new(mult_node.inputs[1], uv_scale_node.outputs[0])
            links.new(combine_uv_node.inputs[i], mult_node.outputs[0])

        # Translate (or possible rotate) UVs.
        mapping_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeMapping")
        mapping_node.vector_type = 'TEXTURE'
        mapping_node.inputs['Rotation'].default_value[2] = self.uv_rotation
        mapping_node.inputs['Location'].default_value[0] = self.uv_translation[0]
        mapping_node.inputs['Location'].default_value[1] = self.uv_translation[1]
        # mapping_node.translation[0] = self.uv_translation[0]
        # mapping_node.translation[1] = self.uv_translation[1]
        # mapping_node.rotation[2] = self.uv_rotation
        links.new(mapping_node.inputs[0], combine_uv_node.outputs[0])

        return mapping_node
        # return combine_uv_node

    def init_nodes(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def load_annotations(cls, path):
        annot_path = path / 'annotations.json'
        if annot_path.exists():
            with open(annot_path, 'r') as f:
                scale = json.load(f).get('scale', 1.0)
                print(f'Loaded scale={scale} from {annot_path}')
        else:
            scale = 1.0
        return scale


class MDLMaterial(NodesMaterial):
    BASE_COLOR_INP_ID = 0
    SUBSURF_COLOR_INP_ID = 3
    METALLIC_INP_ID = 4
    SPECULAR_INP_ID = 5
    ROUGHNESS_INP_ID = 7
    IOR_INP_ID = 14
    TRANSMISSION_INP_ID = 15
    NORMAL_INP_ID = 16

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls, mat_path, **kwargs):
        if not mat_path.exists():
            raise FileNotFoundError(mat_path)

        parsed_dict = mdl.parse_mdl(mat_path)

        for k, v in parsed_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v, str):
                kwargs[k] = Path(mat_path.parent, v)
            elif isinstance(v, float):
                kwargs[k] = v
            elif isinstance(v, tuple):
                kwargs[k] = v
            elif v is None:
                warnings.warn(f'Value for {k} is None')
            else:
                raise ValueError(f'Unknown value type: {v}')

        return cls(mdl_path=mat_path, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self,
                 *,
                 mdl_path,
                 base_color,
                 roughness,
                 opacity=1.0,
                 normal=None,
                 metallic=0.0,
                 glow=0.0,
                 translucence=0.0,
                 subsurface_color=None,
                 ior=1.450,
                 height=None,
                 height_scale=1.0,
                 **kwargs):
        self.mdl_path = mdl_path
        self.base_color = base_color
        self.opacity = opacity
        self.roughness = roughness
        self.normal = normal
        self.metallic = metallic
        self.translucence = translucence
        self.glow = glow
        self.subsurface_color = subsurface_color
        self.ior = ior
        self.height = height
        self.height_scale = height_scale

        self.tex_nodes = []
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def substance(self):
        return self.mdl_path.parent.parent.name

    @property
    def source_name(self):
        return self.mdl_path.stem

    def _add_input(self, value, input_id, color_space, bsdf_node,
                   invert=False):
        if not value:
            raise ValueError('Value is None')

        nodes = self.bobj.node_tree.nodes
        links = self.bobj.node_tree.links

        if isinstance(value, Path):
            tex_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
            # tex_node.color_space = color_space
            tex_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(
                filepath=str(value))
            if color_space != 'COLOR':
                tex_node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True

            self.tex_nodes.append(tex_node)
            if invert:
                opacity_invert_node = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeInvert')
                links.new(opacity_invert_node.inputs[0], tex_node.outputs[0])
                links.new(bsdf_node.inputs[input_id],
                          opacity_invert_node.outputs[0])
            else:
                links.new(bsdf_node.inputs[input_id], tex_node.outputs[0])
        elif isinstance(value, tuple):
            if invert:
                bsdf_node.inputs[input_id].default_value = \
                    tuple(1 - v for v in value)
            else:
                bsdf_node.inputs[input_id].default_value = value
        elif isinstance(value, float):
            bsdf_node.inputs[input_id].default_value = \
                (1 - value) if invert else value
        else:
            RuntimeError(f'Invalid type {value!r}')

    def init_nodes(self):
        self.tex_nodes.clear()
        nodes = self.bobj.node_tree.nodes
        links = self.bobj.node_tree.links

        bsdf_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled")
        bsdf_node.distribution = 'MULTI_GGX'

        if self.normal:
            normal_map_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeNormalMap")
            normal_map_node.space = 'TANGENT'

            if isinstance(self.normal, Path):
                normal_tex_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
                # normal_tex_node.color_space = 'NONE'
                normal_tex_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(
                    filepath=str(self.normal))
                normal_tex_node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True
                self.tex_nodes.append(normal_tex_node)
                links.new(normal_map_node.inputs[1], normal_tex_node.outputs[0])
            elif isinstance(self.normal, tuple):
                normal_map_node.inputs[1].default_value = self.normal

        if not self.base_color:
            raise RuntimeError('Base color must be defined.')
        else:
            self._add_input(self.base_color, self.BASE_COLOR_INP_ID, 'COLOR',
                            bsdf_node)

        if self.subsurface_color:
            self._add_input(self.subsurface_color, self.SUBSURF_COLOR_INP_ID,
                            'COLOR', bsdf_node)

        if self.roughness:
            self._add_input(self.roughness, self.ROUGHNESS_INP_ID, 'NONE',
                            bsdf_node)

        if self.metallic:
            self._add_input(self.metallic, self.METALLIC_INP_ID, 'NONE',
                            bsdf_node)

        # if self.opacity:
        #     self._add_input(self.opacity, self.SPECULAR_INP_ID, 'NONE',
        #                     bsdf_node, invert=False)

        if self.ior:
            self._add_input(self.ior, self.IOR_INP_ID, 'NONE', bsdf_node)

        output_node = nodes["Material Output"]

        if self.height:
            bump_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeBump")
            bump_node.inputs[0].default_value = self.height_scale
            if self.normal:
                links.new(bump_node.inputs[3], normal_map_node.outputs[0])

            if isinstance(self.height, Path):
                height_tex_node = nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeTexImage")
                # height_tex_node.color_space = 'NONE'
                height_tex_node.image = bpy.data.images.load(
                    filepath=str(self.height))
                height_tex_node.image.colorspace_settings.is_data = True

                self.tex_nodes.append(height_tex_node)
                links.new(bump_node.inputs[0],
                          height_tex_node.outputs[0])
            elif isinstance(self.height, float):
                bump_node.inputs[0].default_value = self.height

            links.new(bsdf_node.inputs[self.NORMAL_INP_ID],
                      bump_node.outputs[0])
        elif self.normal:
            links.new(bsdf_node.inputs[self.NORMAL_INP_ID],
                      normal_map_node.outputs[0])

        self.connect_scale_node(self.tex_nodes)

        links.new(output_node.inputs[0], bsdf_node.outputs[0])

    def mean_roughness(self):
        if isinstance(self.roughness, Path):
            if (self.roughness.name.endswith('.exr')
                    or self.roughness.name.endswith('.hdr')):
                roughness_map = load_hdr(self.roughness)
            else:
                roughness_map = load_image(self.roughness)
            if len(roughness_map.shape) == 3:
                roughness_map = roughness_map[:, :, 0]

            return roughness_map.mean()
        elif isinstance(self.roughness, float):
            return self.roughness

        raise RuntimeError('Invalid roughness value')
```

But for some reasons, the material is not loaded properly into blender as I render my mesh. the following image is what I expect to see:

[image: the expected rendered image]

But I am getting the following rendered image, in which the texture is incorrect and the look is unrealistic:

[image: the actual rendered image]

Here is also the link to brender module which I used for the purpose of rendering:

https://github.com/keunhong/brender/tree/cfeedffba72c6ca79926231c31e36e7ff249eacd

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems that you are trying to find out how to setup a PBR material using python? If that's the case, you should definitely edit your proposal to make that clear, as well as show exactly what you are doing so far so that people have a clear context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I rephrased the question, hopefully it is more clear now.